# Issue on Adding Arrow Content After Button

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to add arrow content after the button

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.btn-warning:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #5A55A3;
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
<button class="btn btn-warning">Button With Arraow out<br /> This is Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arrow is just off the page to the right (note the horizontal scroll bar). It's absolutely positioned relative to the document and `left:100%` places it just past the right edge of the page. It seems that you want the arrow to be absolutely positioned relative to the button element itself.

Absolute positioning places an element "at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block." (See [absolute position @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).) So the button itself needs to be "positioned".

In my example, below, I've added `position:relative` to the button element so that it becomes a "positioned ancestor".

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.btn-warning {
  position: relative;
}

.btn-warning:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #5A55A3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-warning">Button With Arraow out<br />This is Test</button>
</div>
```